# Addressing Patient Clustering in Tumor Gene Expression?

Tags: clustering, pca, bias

I have RNAseq data from various tumors, many of which were extracted from the same patients. These tumors are classified with categorical values, and my objective is to compare gene expression across each category. However, a challenge arises when conducting PCA analysis, as the gene expression of the tumors leads to patient clustering. Consequently, if I were to perform a differential expression analysis between the tumor categories, the majority of the observed differences in gene expression would stem from the inherent biological variations among patients.

Is there a way to correct for this effect and prevent it from overshadowing the genuine biological differences I am attempting to analyze?